# Using `decreasing_by` to prove termination in Lean 4

Tags: lean4, termination

> **Warning:** This was written for Lean v4.5.0. To make the accepted answer work, please use v4.6.0-rc1.

I would like to define an elementary `quicksort` function for lists in Lean 4. The following declaration can be used in computations but I want to fill the `sorry`:

```
def qsort (L : List Int) : List Int :=
  match L with
  | [] => []
  | x :: l => qsort (p1 x l) ++ [x] ++ qsort (p2 x l)
    where
      p1 (x : Int) (l : List Int) : List Int := (l.filter (· ≤ x))
      p2 (x : Int) (l : List Int) : List Int := (l.filter (· > x))
  decreasing_by {sorry}

#eval qsort [1, -3, 4, 5, 2]  -- [-3, 1, 2, 4, 5]
```

The tactic state that I see in the Lean infoview is the following:

```
2 goals

x: Int
l: List Int
⊢ (invImage (fun a => sizeOf a) instWellFoundedRelation).1 (qsort.p1 x l) (x :: l)

x: Int
l: List Int
⊢ (invImage (fun a => sizeOf a) instWellFoundedRelation).1 (qsort.p2 x l) (x :: l)
```

I think that, to prove that the recursion terminates, it should be enough to prove the following proposition:

```
List.length (qsort.p1 x l) < List.length (x::l) : Prop
```

and similarly for `qsort.p2`. So I would like the expression

```
invImage (fun a => sizeOf a) instWellFoundedRelation
```

that I see in the Lean infoview to be

```
invImage (List.length : List Int → Nat) Nat.lt_wfRel
```

but I have not been able to make this appear in the goal. Indeed, this is a term of type `WellFoundedRelation (List Int)` whose first projection is the relation `r L1 L2` defined by `List.length L1 < List.length L2`.

If I could make this appear in the goal, then I should to be able to conclude by proving the proposition `List.length (qsort.p1 x l) < List.length (x::l)`.

I have looked at the answers to the following question

- [How to prove the termination of Ackermann in Lean?](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/q/2159)

but I have not been able to use `termination_by` in my example, so I am trying to use `decreasing_by` instead, which has the effect of making Lean enter tactic mode and display a goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow the examples in [TPIL4 Chapter 8](https://lean-lang.org/theorem_proving_in_lean4/induction_and_recursion.html#well-founded-recursion-and-induction).  (Edit: This answer is for the new syntax, which changed in Lean 4.6.  See the [4.6 release notes](https://github.com/leanprover/lean4/releases/tag/v4.6.0-rc1) for a comparison with the former syntax.) In particular:

- `termination_by` specifies what the decreasing value is.

  - By default is the built-in value `sizeOf`.
  - In this case it is better to go with `length`.
  - If the parameter, is to the right of the colon, then you supply a function—e.g. `termination_by l => l.length`, `termination_by (fun x : List Int => x.length)`, or `termination_by List.length`.
  - If the parameter, `L` in this case, is to the left of the colon, then you just give the value in terms of `L`, e.g. `termination_by L.length`.
- `decreasing_by` is the proof that the value from `termination_by` is decreasing.

  - Use `all_goals simp_wf` to get rid of the boilerplate.  (`all_goals` since you have multiple recursive calls).
  - After that, in this case, the proof is mostly just applying the lemma [`List.length_filter_le`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Std/Data/List/Lemmas.html#List.length_filter_le) (found in `Std`).
- `termination_by` and `decreasing_by` go before `where`, else Lean applies them to the last auxiliary function `p2`.

```
import Std

def qsort : (L : List Int) -> (List Int)
| [] => []
| x :: l => qsort (p1 x l) ++ [x] ++ qsort (p2 x l)
termination_by l => l.length
decreasing_by
  all_goals simp_wf
  /-
  x : Int
  l : List Int
  ⊢ List.length (qsort.p1 x l) < Nat.succ (List.length l)
  
  x : Int
  l : List Int
  ⊢ List.length (qsort.p2 x l) < Nat.succ (List.length l)
  -/
  . calc
      (qsort.p1 x l).length ≤ l.length     := by unfold qsort.p1; simp [List.length_filter_le]
      _                     < l.length + 1 := by simp
  . calc
      (qsort.p2 x l).length ≤ l.length     := by unfold qsort.p2; simp [List.length_filter_le]
      _                     < l.length + 1 := by simp
where
  p1 (x : Int) (l : List Int) : List Int := (l.filter (· ≤ x))
  p2 (x : Int) (l : List Int) : List Int := (l.filter (· > x))
```

---

The form I wrote the recursive definition is equivalent to yours and probably more idiomatic.  But if you go with your version where the parameter `L` is to the left of the colon, then `termination_by` would look different, as follows (no `=>`):

```
def qsort (L : List Int) : List Int :=
  match L with
  | [] => []
  | x :: l => qsort (p1 x l) ++ [x] ++ qsort (p2 x l)
termination_by L.length
decreasing_by
  all_goals simp_wf
  . sorry
  . sorry
where
  p1 (x : Int) (l : List Int) : List Int := (l.filter (· ≤ x))
  p2 (x : Int) (l : List Int) : List Int := (l.filter (· > x))
```

Comment: Using `List.length` feels much more natural, thanks! But `termination_by l => List.length l` produces the error message `function 'l' not found in current declaration`. I don't know why :-/  And if I try `termination_by _ => List.length` then, after `all_goals simp_wf` the goal is changed to `False`.

Comment: @Matematiflo I think there is some misunderstanding.  I gave you complete code which I tested in Lean.  It uses a more idiomatic style IMHO too.  Does this code not work in your version of Lean?  (Indentation matters here.  Lean 4 is white space sensitive like Python.)  If so what version is it?  Also  `termination_by` should *not* go inside the `decreasing_by` proof.

Comment: @Matematiflo I think I now understand your confusion.  See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks @Jason-Rute. Indeed, there must be a problem with the version of Lean 4 that I am using (leanprover/lean4:v4.5.0
 in my lean-toolchain file) because when I type in your code (which indeed works if I test it on live.lean-lang.org), after `termination_by L.length`, I get `unexpected end of input; expected '=>'`. I'll investigate further and report back here when I solve the issue or if I end up not being able to. Maybe I just need to use a more recent release of Lean.

Comment: @Matematiflo Oh, indeed it looks like `termination_by` syntax was changed in Lean 4.6 ([release notes](https://github.com/leanprover/lean4/releases/tag/v4.6.0-rc1)), which is still a release candidate. I'm going to leave my answer remain since it is going to be the correct answer soon, but if you look at that release note, you can see the 4.5 syntax, which requires one to also supply the function name in `termination_by`. (In 4.6, each function gets its own `termination_by`.  Previously there was one `termination_by` for a declaration, like yours which defines 3 functions simultaneously.)

Comment: Thanks for all the pointers @Jason-Rute! I apologize for not mentioning the version earlier (silly mistake). And indeed with 4.6.0-rc1 it works perfectly :-)