# Pattern Matching on List x Fin

Tags: lean, lean4

So, here is the example I'm working on:

```lean
def from_bytes_be(bytes:List byte)(i: Fin bytes.length) : Nat :=
  match bytes,p:i.val with  
  | b::_,0 => b.val
  | b::bs,k+1 =>
      have q0 : i.val = k+1 := by sorry -- should be easy??
      have q1 : k < bs.length := by sorry
      let im1 : Fin bs.length := {val:= k, isLt:=by exact q1}
      (256 * (from_bytes_be bs im1)) + b.val
```

I'm stuck trying to prove `q1` and realised that I can't even prove `q0` (which I thought should be easy via `simp`).  I also tried pattern matching directly with `match bytes,i` but couldn't figure out how to match against `Fin.ofNat 0`.

Any thoughts appreciated!!

Comment: Proving `p0` in Agda needs using the so-called "inspect idiom" which I don't know how to do in Lean

Comment: First, I recommend following the pattern from the answer here: https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/3840/termination-for-wrapped-fin-in-lean4. This includes matching over all of `i`, not just its value.  It should be easier to work with.

Comment: Funny ... I asked that as well!!

Comment: And, I tried doing the full match but failed.  Will try again.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Jason, I figured out the answer:

```lean
def from_bytes_be(bytes:List byte)(i: Fin bytes.length) : Nat :=
  match bytes, i with
  | b::_, {val:=0,isLt:=_} => b.val
  | b::bs, {val:=k+1,isLt:=p} =>
      have q : k < bs.length := by exact Nat.succ_lt_succ_iff.mp p
      let im1 : Fin bs.length := {val:= k, isLt:=by exact q}
      (256 * (from_bytes_be bs im1)) + b.val
```

Seems like I keep bumping my head against the same thing!

Comment: `by exact q` should be the same as `q` (and same with the other `by exact …`).